# Execute the datetime command received as a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have date information `"20.days.from_now"` in a string format. With this datum, I should be able to find the exact date at any given point in time. But I couldn't find a way to execute it.

Tried:

```
1. "20.days.from_now".to_datetime => returns DateTime.now.beginning_of_day + 20.seconds
2. "20.days.from_now".to_datetime => returns Time.now.beginning_of_day + 20.seconds
```

Can't pass this as an argument to the `Time`/`DateTime` methods.

Is there an efficient way to achieve this?

Possible inputs could be:

```
1. "20.days.from_now"
2. "45.seconds.from_now"
3. "-11.months.from_now"
4. "3.years.from_now"
5. "15.hours.from_now"
6. "860.minutes.from_now"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Rails has no built-in way to do this (short of `eval`, which you **definitely don't want**).

You'll need to write a parser, probably using regular expressions, specific for your use case.

Try something like:

```
ALLOWED_UNITS = %w(years months days hours minutes seconds)

if str =~ /\A(-?\d+)\.(\w+)\.from_now\z/ and
    ALLOWED_UNITS.include?($2)
  $1.to_i.public_send($2).from_now
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You first want to parse a number then its unit. You could achieve it by:

```
def parse_date_from_string(str)
  number = str.split(".")[0].to_i
  unit = str.split(".")[1]
  return number.send(unit).from_now
end
```

Given your suggested inputs, the outputs would be:

```
[21] pry(main)> parse_date_from_string("20.days.from_now")
=> Sat, 01 Sep 2018 17:40:19 -03 -03:00
[22] pry(main)> parse_date_from_string("45.seconds.from_now")
=> Sun, 12 Aug 2018 17:41:04 -03 -03:00
[23] pry(main)> parse_date_from_string("-11.months.from_now")
=> Tue, 12 Sep 2017 17:40:19 -03 -03:00
[24] pry(main)> parse_date_from_string("3.years.from_now")
=> Thu, 12 Aug 2021 17:40:19 -03 -03:00
[25] pry(main)> parse_date_from_string("15.hours.from_now")
=> Mon, 13 Aug 2018 08:40:19 -03 -03:00
[26] pry(main)> parse_date_from_string("860.minutes.from_now")
=> Mon, 13 Aug 2018 08:00:19 -03 -03:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @matthewd. You could use `eval` but please don't.

I would not use regex though.

Just split string and process it:

```
 parts = input.split('.')
 # assuming first part is always a number
 number = parts[0].to_i
 # what methods you allow user to chain
 allowed_methods = %w[days seconds ...] 
 method_chain = parts[1..-1]
 raise 'forbidden' unless method_chain.all? { |m| allowed_methods.include?(m) }
 # just invoke methods one by one
 res = method_chain.reduce(number) { |r, m| r.call(m) }
```

Processing fully depends on what your input is expected to be